# Need help to change markers based on horizontal scrolling on list react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-listview, react-native-maps

i need to highlight the marker based on the corresponding restaurant selected in the horizontal list and on scroll the marker highlight needs to change

any tips or example code to achieve this would be a great help.

i'm using react-native-maps library

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you map list elements with the markers on creation, you can retrieve which element is displayed like this:

```
int last = listView1.getLastVisiblePosition();  

int first = listView1.getFirstVisiblePosition();
```

so after scroll, when you notify change to adapter, you can change color of specific marker:

```
marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE));
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps to achieve this:

- Set resturantId  as Tag to each Marker.
- Add scroll listener to your ListView and on scroll stop get the position of
  of last visible item like this: **int last =  listView.getLastVisiblePosition();**
- Get the id of the current focused item and apply a Loop on All markers and if Tag of marker matches with the resturantId then change marker icon accordingly and a different icon for all other markers.

This would help you.